# Array Count Countdown

Tags: objective-c, arrays, count

I have this Array:

```
self.playerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FIRST", @"SECOND", @"THIRD", @"FOURTH", @"FIFTH", @"SIXT", @"SEVENTH", @"EIGTH", @"NINTH", @"TENTH", @"ELEVENTH", @"LAST", nil];
```

Everytime, the User play and make a wrong Answer, a Label is updated to the next Object in this Array. Like: Question, wrong Answer = SECOND, wrong Answer = THIRD and so on.

Now i want to implement a second Label, that tells the User, how much Moves he have left. In this example he have 12 Moves.

But i really don't know how to tell my second Label that it should subtract 1 Move everytime. Does anyone have an answer for me?

I began with

```
self.movesLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Moves: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.playerArray count]];
```

So the Label tells the right Number of Moves. And now i need to subtract 1 every time a wrong answer was given.

Thank you!

EDIT:

The first Array works with the following Code:

In ViewDidLoad:

```
self.playerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FIRST", @"SECOND", @"THIRD", @"FOURTH", @"FIFTH", @"SIXT", @"SEVENTH", @"EIGTH", @"NINTH", @"TENTH", @"ELEVENTH", @"LAST", nil];
_labelIndex = 0;


[self updateTurnLabel];

self.turnLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WHATS YOUR %@ GUESS?", self.playerLabel];
```

The method:

```
-(void) updateTurnLabel {

self.playerLabel = [self.playerArray objectAtIndex:_labelIndex % self.playerArray.count]; _labelIndex++;



}
```

Comment: So how are you tracking the position of the first array and did you try subtracting?

Comment: Ive edited the Code how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of remaining attempts is

```
self.playerArray.count - self.labelIndex
```